Can any one teach me about proof of Theorem 7 in page 282 of the Evans's PDE book more friendly?
I think that I am begginer of PDE. I am reading the Evan's PDE, p.282, Theorem 7 and some question arises :


Q.1. First underlined statement : Where did $C$ come from? In previous sentence Evans wrote that "In particular choosing $\alpha= ( k, 0 , \dots , 0 ), (0,k, \dots,0), \dots, (0, \dots , k )$, ". Why such choice allows us to deduce the first underlined inequality?
Q.2. Second underlined statement : Likewise, where did $C$ come from? And in procedure of deriving the $(18)$ from the $(20)$, $||u||_{H^{k}(\mathbb{R}^n)} \le  ||(iy)^{\alpha}\hat{u}||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}$? If so, why?
Q.3. Final underlined equality : Why the equality is true? How can we derive the equality? My one trial, by using Theorem 4.3.2. ( p. 181 ) in the Evans's book :

Theorem 2. ( Properties of Fourier transform ). Assume $u,v \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Then

(i) $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u \bar{v} dx =\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\hat{u}\bar{\hat{v}} dy$,
(ii) $\hat{D^{\alpha}u}=(iy)^{\alpha}\hat{u}$ for each multiindex $\alpha$ such that $D^{\alpha}u \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$,
(iii) $( u *v)^{\wedge} =(2\pi)^{n/2}\hat{u}\hat{v}$,
(iv) $u = (\hat{u}\check) $.


, is as follows ( We omit $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, which is the domain of integration ) :
$$(-1)^{|\alpha|} \int \phi \bar{u_{\alpha}} dx = (-1)^{|{\alpha}|} \int \hat{\phi} \bar{\hat{u_{\alpha}}} dy := (-1)^{|{\alpha}|} \int \hat{\phi} \overline{ (((iy)^{\alpha} \hat{u})\check))^{\wedge} } dy 
 \stackrel{?}{=} (-1)^{|\alpha|} \int \hat{\phi} \overline{ (((iy)^{\alpha})\check) ((\hat{u})\check) )^{\wedge}   }dy \stackrel{?}{=} (-1)^{|\alpha|} \int \hat{\phi} \overline{ ((iy)^{\alpha})\check)^{\wedge} ( ( \hat{u})\check)^{\wedge}}
\stackrel{?}{=} (-1)^{|\alpha|}\int \hat{\phi} \overline{(iy)^{\alpha} \hat{u}}dy = (-1)^{|\alpha|}\int \hat{\phi} \overline{(iy)^{\alpha}}\bar{\hat{u}} dy \stackrel{?}{=} \int (iy)^{\alpha} \hat{\phi}\bar{\hat{u}}dy $$
Each steps marked by the question symbols are true? Third and Fourth  equality : The Fourier and its inverse transform is distributive under the multiplication ?  Fifth equality : $ ( (iy)^{\alpha} \check)^{\wedge}=(iy)^{\alpha} $? By the above theorem $2$, for $u\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$,  $u = (\hat{u}\check) $ . Perhaps, $ ( u \check)^{\wedge} = u$ is also true?  If it is not true in general, how about for $u=(iy)^{\alpha}$? Final equality : To show the final equality, perhaps, $(-1)^{|\alpha|} \overline{(iy)^{\alpha}} = (iy)^{\alpha}$?
I don't understand these three questions at all until now. Can anyone explain those more friendly?

I'll preface this answer by saying that these types of question can be hard to answer in a satisfactory manner since it's not always easy to put yourselves in the author's shoes, so please excuse me if I don't understand or do exactly what Evans probably intended, especially for your first question.

I'm not exactly sure myself why Evans chooses these indexes in particular and not all of those such that $|\alpha| = k$, but it could maybe be a typo in the equation below, with $|y|^{2k}$ where it could have been $|y_j|^{2k}$. Indeed, if it had been $|y_j|^{2k}$, then it would make sense to choose $\alpha = (0, \cdots, 0, k, 0, \cdots, 0)$ with $k$ in the $i$-th position.
Either way, the overall idea is to use a few equalities and inequalities related to multi-indices.
For example, we have:
$$\left(\sum_{j = 1}^n x_j\right)^k = \sum_{|\alpha| = k} \binom{k}{\alpha} x^\alpha$$
where $$\binom{k}{\alpha} := \frac{k!}{\prod_{j = 1}^n \alpha_j!}$$
This is a generalisation of the binomial theorem called the multinomial theorem.
If you apply it to $x_j = |y_j|^{2}$, you get:
$$|y|^{2k} = \left(\sum_{j = 1}^n |y_j|^2\right)^k = \sum_{|\alpha| = k} \binom{k}{\alpha} \prod_{j = 1}^n |y_j|^{2\alpha_j} =  \sum_{|\alpha| = k} \binom{k}{\alpha} |y^\alpha|^2$$
so that:
$$\begin{split}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |y|^{2k}|\hat{u}|^2\,\mathrm{d}y &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left(\sum_{|\alpha| = k} \binom{k}{\alpha} |y^\alpha|^2\right) |\hat{u}|^2\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&\leq \left(\sup_{|\alpha| = k} \binom{k}{\alpha}\right) \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left(\sum_{|\alpha| = k}|y^\alpha \hat{u}|^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&\leq \left(\sup_{|\alpha| = k} \binom{k}{\alpha}\right) \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left(\sum_{|\alpha| = k}|D^\alpha u|^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}y =: C_k \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |D^k u|^2\,\mathrm{d}y\end{split}$$

Here we have the same kind of deal. This is a trick that's pretty basic but quite helpful: instead of trying to prove the inequality $$|y|^{2|\alpha|} \leq C \left(1 + |y|^k\right)^2$$
via some direct upper-bounding, you instead study the function $f : t \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto \displaystyle\frac{t^{|\alpha|}}{1 + t^k}$ and try to show it is bounded by relying on its continuity, and then apply that to $t = |y|$.
It's pretty clear that the limit at $+\infty$ of $f$ is $0$ if $|\alpha| < k$ and $1$ if $|\alpha| = k$, $f$ is non-negative, and $f$ is continuous on $[0, +\infty)$, therefore (left as a quick exercise) $f$ is bounded on $[0,+\infty)$, and we have the desired inequality.

You are on the right track but also you are overcomplicating the problem a tiny bit. Indeed the only thing you need to prove is: $$\overline{(iy)^\alpha} = (-1)^{|\alpha|}(iy)^\alpha$$
Once this is proven true, you'll be able to proceed like this:
$$\int (iy)^{\alpha} \hat{\phi}\bar{\hat{u}}\,\mathrm{d}y = (-1)^{|\alpha|}\int \hat{\phi} \overline{(iy)^{\alpha}\hat{u}}\,\mathrm{d}y = (-1)^{|\alpha|}\int \hat{\phi} \overline{\widehat{u_\alpha}}\,\mathrm{d}y = (-1)^{|\alpha|}\int \phi \overline{u_\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}y$$
However, because all the components of $y$ are real, we have:
$$\begin{split}\overline{(iy)^\alpha} &= \overline{\prod_{j = 1}^n (iy_j)^{\alpha_j}}\\
&= \prod_{j = 1}^n \left(\overline{iy_j}\right)^{\alpha_j}\\
&= \prod_{j = 1}^n \left(-iy_j\right)^{\alpha_j}\\
&= \left(\prod_{j = 1}^n \left(-1\right)^{\alpha_j}\right) \left(\prod_{j = 1}^n \left(iy_j\right)^{\alpha_j}\right)\\
&= (-1)^{|\alpha|} (iy)^\alpha\end{split}$$
and we have shown what we wanted.



Brilliance ! Can I ask more for making certainly sure ? 1) For the first answer, what does the notations $y_j$ and $\alpha_j$ are exactly means?   I don't know why $\left(\sum_{j = 1}^n |y_j|^2\right)^k = \sum_{|\alpha| = k} \binom{k}{\alpha} \prod_{j = 1}^n |y_j|^{2\alpha_j}$. And I don't understand why $\sum_{|\alpha| = k}|y^\alpha \hat{u}|^2=\sum_{|\alpha| = k}|D^\alpha u|^2$. By the $(19)$ in the image in my question ?
2) For the third answer, $\hat{u_{\alpha}} := ((iy)^{\alpha}\hat{u})\check )^{\wedge} = (iy)^{\alpha}\hat{u}$? The fourier transform of inverse transform is an identity?


And, to show the $(18)$ in the above image in my question, $||u||{H^{k}(\mathbb{R}^n)} \le  ||(iy)^{\alpha}\hat{u}||{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}$?


Anyway thank you very much.

@Plantation 1) The $y_j$s and $\alpha_j$s correspond to the coordinates of $y$ and $\alpha$ respectively. As for the multinomial theorem, it is used in Evans's book but I think he assumes it, which means you'll need to find a proof of it somewhere, but Wikipedia should have you covered iirc. Point $(i)$ of the Theorem $2$ you rewrote down is applicable when $v = u$, which gives $\int |v|^2 = \int |\hat{v}|^2$, and it should be easy to see that $|y^\alpha|^2 = |iy^\alpha|^2$.


Yes, the inverse Fourier transform is, like its name implies, the inverse of the Fourier transform. Depending on the definition there might be a multiplicative constant I suppose, but that wouldn't change anything.



No that shouldn't be true, since what you'll have is instead that $$|u|{H^k}^2 = \sum{|\alpha| \leq k} |D^\alpha u|{L^2}^2 = \sum{|\alpha| \leq k} |(iy)^\alpha\hat{u}|_{L^2}^2$$ so that what you'll do is sum the estimates $(20)$.


Learning and getting used to these kinds of multi-index manipulations is certainly not easy, so don't feel too down if you don't think it's very natural yet. It will come with more experience.

Aha. For 3), perhaps, in fact, each $C$ in $(20)$ depends on $\alpha$?

@Plantation Yes but there's a finite amount of them so you can take the $\sup$.

O.K. I got it. Nice comment. I learned a lot. Thanks for kindness and generosity ! ( P.s. From the perspective of doing algebraic geometry, the world of partial differential equations occasionally seems a bit difficult for me.  :) )
